# Copy/Clone one USB stick to another with different size and format

Tags: linux, dd, file-copy

I need to upgrade a USB stick I am using as it has become too small (16 GB) and the new stick is 64 GB which is too large, requires NTFS format.  I have used this to reformat the new stick: `sudo mkntfs --fast --label PDNS_BUDrive /dev/sdb1`

I have searched the web for references and have found several.  The majority of the references suggest to use DD.  Following a recommendation I used the following: `sudo dd if=/dev/sdc1 of=/dev/sdb1 bs=4M`

This appeared to work at first glance, but then I discovered that it had not only cloned the data, but also the UUID, label and old format designation (vfat). So my FSTAB did mounted both using the old UUID and did not find/mount the new stick, since it could not find the UUID.

What did I do wrong, or what should I have done??....RDK

Comment: I seem to recall that copy ("cp") copies files but not current permissions?  If I use "cp -a" do I also need -r?

Comment: If permissions are not critical, is this the way to go?

Comment: WOW...  Ok, I'm a NOOBS and not 100% comfortable with this copy/clone operation.  I  have a server which depends on me doing the right thing.  I did the GOOGLing and found references to DD and cp, but not information about the side issues of a different size, different format and permissions.  It sounded like DD was the right answer so I did it, but I found out differently.  Now, will you cut me a break?....

Comment: Clone is an exact copy to exact copy or same size drive/format to same. dd is an extremely powerful tool and then dd also has the nickname Data Destroyer as any typo or incorrect drive totally erases data. My drives change as flash drive mounted as sdc becomes sda on reboot. Windows formats like FAT32 & NTFS do not support Linux ownership & permissions, so if using those formats not an issue. Often better to use Windows tools for Windows & Linux tools for Linux.

Comment: Hmmm, looks like some earlier comments have been deleted? OK, what would be the right "cp" command for my problem?

Comment: OK, I will repeat my question, where would be the correct linux command to copy all of the contents from one USB stick (16 GB, vfat) to another (64BGB, NTSC)...?

Comment: `cp -a` which I specified in the first now deleted comment.

Comment: OK, I saw that, but did not understand the description: "archive".  Now, looking at the full manual link, I see the additional comments about recursive and permissions.  I finally used the equivalent, but without realizing it.  Here is the command I used "cp -r -p /mnt/usbdrive/* /mnt/BU_Drive/".  Write it up as an answer and I will accept it...